# Grails - Pass a link as a parameter

Tags: grails, hyperlink, arguments, href

I have implemented an email sharing service in my web application. People can click on the `email button` and access a form with which they can send emails to whom they want.

I would like to set a default `subject` and `body`.

In the `default body text` of the email, I would like to pass the link of the page people want to share. Surely it is possible to do so but I do not manage to. 
So far it has been a dead end to try to pass the link in the `value` argument of my text editor. I cannot think if any other way to do it.

Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you pass data to any other fields that you want to populate.

For example your controller returns a model `emailShare` that contains `subject`, `body` and `url` etc

In your gsp, lets say you have a textarea for the body of your email,

```
<g:textField name="emailSubject" value="${emailShare.subject}" />
<g:textArea name="emailBody" value="${emailShare.url}" rows="5" cols="40"/>
```

This will set the `url` as the default text in the textarea, which can also be further edited to add more text.

Comment: Ah ah, you were right actually. For some reason I was desperately trying to do it from the view, when it was so simple to pass it as a model from the controller :)

Comment: One of those `*ding*` `*lightbulb*` moments :D

Answer (score 1):

You can get the location of the current page using JavaScript with `document.URL`  Then you can just set a hidden field on your form and submit it with your email request.  For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function setLocation(urlField) {
       urlField.value = document.URL
     }
   </script>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="exampleForm" name="exampleForm" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="url"  name="url"/>
    <input name="submit" value="submit" type="button" onclick="setLocation(this.form.url);" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```